# Exclude a specific implicit from a Scala project

Tags: scala, sbt, implicit-conversion, scalafix

How can I prevent the usage of a specific implicit in my scala code?

For example, I was recently bit by the default `Codec` provided by https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/68bad81726d15d03a843dc476d52cbbaf52fb168/src/library/scala/io/Codec.scala#L76. 
Is there a way to ensure that any code that calls for an `implicit codec: Codec` never uses the one provided by `fallbackSystemCodec`? 
Alternatively, is it possible to block all implicit Codecs?

Is this something that should be doable using scalafix?

Comment: I'm not sure about the scale on which you want to ban the usage of this codec, but you are aware of the `import foo.bar.baz.{stuff_i_dont_need => _, _}` syntax?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin That's an excellent point and works in the small but I'd like to do this across multiple modules in an sbt project. This will also still allow the code to compile if I forget to import `=> _`. I want a way to protect myself from that mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Scalafix can [inspect implicit arguments](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalafix/blob/master/docs/developers/semantic-tree.md#look-up-implicit-argument) using `SemanticTree`. [Here](https://github.com/mario-galic/scalafix-exclude-implicits) is an example solution by defining a custom scalafix rule.

Given

```
import scala.io.Codec

object Hello {
  def foo(implicit codec: Codec) = 3
  foo
}
```

we can define a custom rule

```
class ExcludedImplicitsRule(config: ExcludedImplicitsRuleConfig)
    extends SemanticRule("ExcludedImplicitsRule") {

...

  override def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch = {
    doc.tree.collect {
      case term: Term if term.synthetic.isDefined => // TODO: Use ApplyTree(func, args)
        val struct = term.synthetic.structure
        val isImplicit = struct.contains("implicit")
        val excludedImplicit = config.blacklist.find(struct.contains)
        if (isImplicit && excludedImplicit.isDefined)
          Patch.lint(ExcludedImplicitsDiagnostic(term, excludedImplicit.getOrElse(config.blacklist.mkString(","))))
        else
          Patch.empty
    }.asPatch
  }

}
```

and corresponding `.scalafix.conf`

```
rule = ExcludedImplicitsRule
ExcludedImplicitsRuleConfig.blacklist = [
  fallbackSystemCodec
]
```

should enable `sbt scalafix` to raise the diagnostic

```
[error] /Users/mario/IdeaProjects/scalafix-exclude-implicits/example-project/scalafix-exclude-implicits-example/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:7:3: error: [ExcludedImplicitsRule] Attempting to pass excluded implicit fallbackSystemCodec to foo'
[error]   foo
[error]   ^^^
[error] (Compile / scalafix) scalafix.sbt.ScalafixFailed: LinterError
```

Note the output of `println(term.synthetic.structure)`

```
Some(ApplyTree(
  OriginalTree(Term.Name("foo")),
  List(
    IdTree(SymbolInformation(scala/io/LowPriorityCodecImplicits#fallbackSystemCodec. => implicit lazy val method fallbackSystemCodec: Codec))
  )
))
```

Clearly the above solution is not efficient as it searches strings, however it should give some direction. Perhaps matching on `ApplyTree(func, args)` would be better.

[scalafix-exclude-implicits-example](https://github.com/mario-galic/scalafix-exclude-implicits/tree/master/example-project/scalafix-exclude-implicits-example) shows how to configure the project to use `ExcludedImplicitsRule`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a new type altogether; this way, nobody will be able to override it in your dependencies. It's essentially the answer I posted to [create an ambiguous low priority implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462253/create-an-ambiguous-low-priority-implicit)

It may not be practical though, if for example you can't change the type.

Comment: Great idea but requires modifying all data models (e.g. can no longer use `Double` but rather `NewDouble`) which seems a bit unwieldy.